# error: Error: Unable to resolve module `./node_modules/react-navigation-stack/dist/views/Header/HeaderTitle` from `index.js`:

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to update my react native project from `0.59.8 to 0.63.3`

In the process, I have created a new project with the latest version and placed package.json dependencies and source js files from the old project.

When I run the app I am getting the below error.

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module 
`./node_modules/react-navigation-stack/dist/views/Header/HeaderTitle` from 
`index.js`:

 "react-native": "0.63.3",
 "react-navigation": "^3.1.4",
 "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.2",
  import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
```

Please help me if you know the solution for this.

Thank you.

Comment: React navigation 3 is no longer maintained, so maybe there are compatibility issues with the new React Native Version.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try "react-navigation": "^4.4.3"
```